# how to patabless result of mysql stored procedure inside temporary

Tags: mysql

I have one stored procedure with one in parameter that returns multiple rows with 3 different columns. I want this result to be inserted inside another table with these 3 column filed and other tables individual fields.

However, when I create the temporary table it shows a blank resultset.

Can anybody help me to sort out this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getContactRolePermission`(
in contactroleid double
-- inout PermissionTableID double
)
BEGIN

select -- entitydetails.id,
 contact.id as userid,
 -- contacttyperolemap.contacttypeId ,
 contacttyperolemap.roleid ,rolepermission.permissionid
 from contacttyperolemap 
 join rolepermission on contacttyperolemap.roleid=rolepermission.roleid
 join entitydetails on  entitydetails.id = contacttyperolemap.ContactTypeID 
 join contact on contact.contactTypeID = entitydetails.id 
 where  contacttyperolemap.contactTypeID = contactroleid
 order by contact.id;

CREATE temporary TABLE tmp(
     ID double ,
    userid double ,
    roleid double ,
    permissionid double
);

END


stored procedures result is
uid rid pid 
2   1   5
2   1   2
2   1   3
2   1   4
2   1   1
23  1   4
23  1   1
23  1   5
23  1   2
23  1   3
26  1   4
26  1   1
26  1   5
26  1   2
26  1   3
```

I want to insert this data inside `userpermission` table

```
schema is
id  uid rid pid
1   10  2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create a view instead of a stored procedure for the first 3 rows. Then in a separate query you can query any columns from that view and join that data with whatever other data you want from other tables. Hopefully I read the question right. Heres an article on creating views: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer; for example, showing how a view can be created, and how it can be queried.

Answer (score 0):

Use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) command to fill target table.

And, your temp table shows empty result, because you have not filled it.

Comment: but how to select resultset column to be inserted inside userpermission table

Comment: i am not able to insert this records inside user permission table as userpermission table has 4 fields and result set is of 3 fields..then how do i  insert it..???

Comment: INSERT...SELECT statement allows you to do it. Just specify columns you need to insert and specify columns you need to select, if table in SELECT has less columns, then pass constant values or use functions to generate values.

Comment: not working properly , unable to insert  ,is there any way to directly insert records of resultset inside userpermission without using temporary table...??

Comment: insert into userpermission (ID, userID, userRoleID, permissionID)
   select (0 ,userid,roleid,permissionid);

Comment: You miss FROM clause in after SELECT clause.

Comment: i have to insert from stored procedure ..and these fields are from resultset(userid,roleid,permissionid)

Comment: You ask about inserting data. Why do not you have INSERT command? If you want to use SELECT as resultset - use INSERT...SELECT command. All must work.

Comment: not getting ur point..sorry..I am new to sql so I dnt knw much..can u please elaborate the solution so that I can find the proper way to do it..????

Comment: Do not worry. We are all people). Please show your last code, where do you have problem?

Comment: CALL getContactRolePermission(@contactroleid)
INSERT INTO userpermission SELECT(@contactroleid);

Comment: but it will not insert into userpermission table as it has 4 fields and my sp has only one input parameter and result set is of 4 fields